# How to identify a specific TCP connection

Tags: tcp

If suppose multiple TCP connections are there in a network , then how will I idnetfy a single TCP connecton uniquely ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a homework question.... from networking 101.

In any case, TCP connections are uniquely identified by the following properties: source IP address, source port, destination address, and destination port.

Do an internet search for "TCP 4-tuple" or "TCP 5-tuple" for more details.